# Reading a list inside an object with lambda

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have these objects:

```
public class HistoricoDTO
{
    public long EquipoId { get; set; }
    public double Valor { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Dia { get;set;}
    public string Mes { get; set; }
    public string Ano { get; set; }

    public List<HistoricoVariableDTO> ValorVariable { get; set; }
}


public class HistoricoVariableDTO
{
    public string Variable { get; set; }
    public double Valor { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to get some values in the property `ValorVariable`, I need to get Valor with Lambda, bu it not working, i haven't been able.

I'm trying to do womething like this:

```
foreach (var item in HistoricoData.Where(x => x.EquipoId.Equals(EquipoIdSelected) && x.Ano.Equals(AnoSelected) && x.ValorVariable.Any(y => y.Variable.Contains(VariableSlected))))
```

I need to acces to the list, I don't know if it right using this:

```
x.ValorVariable.Any(y => y.Variable.Contains(VariableSlected))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Question is not clear. What aren't you managing to do? Do you get an error? What is the problem with what you have?

Comment: Tell us what your goal is and whats not working

Answer (score 0):

Your need to store your result in a variable first and then loop through that output variable using AsEnumerable() such as:

```
var output = HistoricoData.Where(x => x.EquipoId.Equals(EquipoIdSelected) && x.Ano.Equals(AnoSelected) && x.ValorVariable.Any(y => y.Variable.Contains(VariableSlected)))

foreach(var item in output.AsEnumerable())//loop through your list here
{....}
```

Comment: No you do not need to.